# Cassandra: CAS Insert applied after a delete but no data in the DB

Tags: cassandra

I'm using CQL CAS Insert after a Delete on the same key in my testcase.
The CAS operation gets "Applied", but in some cases when I check the DB after the CAS Insert the data is not stored.

I have seen this problem on 2.0.8 and 2.0.9, but not on 2.1.0.

This is not a problem if I run with Debug on.
Also a Thread.sleep(1) between the delete and the CAS Insert helps.

I know this could to be a timestamp issue, but why is the CAS operation "Applied" but no data inserted.

The problem does not occur when I Insert without CAS after the Delete.

I have tested on a single cassandra node and also with the embedded cassandra.

Has anyone else seen this problem?